# A tale of two Victorian houses: one cracking, one sloping. Potential causes?

Tags: crack, old-house, level, slope

- Did a viewing of two houses in London, revealing different problems.
- What could be causing these issues?
- Which one is potentially more serious?

**Mr Slopy**

- No visible internal cracks inside; ground floor fine.
- Externally the levels seem fine; maybe apart from the sills.
  [image]
- However on the first floor the radiator alignment seemed a bit at an angle; retrospectively the corner also seems off.
  [image]
- So I put a pencil (which is not even perfectly round) on the floor and it rolled down the expected slope.
- The laminated floor is on-top of older wooden one.
  [image]

**Mr Crackling**

[image]

- Render removed, quite rough job, some brick damage.
- Middle of window sill cracked; strange that not at joints.
  [image]
- Suspiciously chunky new concrete (not lime) mortar joints.
  [image]
- The window sill is also craked in the middle at the back.
  [image]
- There are visible vertical cracks from inside at bay window joints.
  [image]
  [image]
- There is also a thunderbolt crack by the door in the reception room containing the bay window.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Foundations.

Some had a 19 or 24" brick foundation just laid on the ground. After 100 or so years things move...

Bought a mid-terrace similar to that and was able to dig under the brick foundation to run a gas pipe.

Comment: Looked this up -- suprising how shoddy Victorian "footing" foundations seem to be; yet these problems are not visible in all houses. Which do you think is the bigger problem; cracks or sloping floor? When you were searching for your house; were defects like that show-stoppers?